# A form that can save/edit after first input

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, forms, html

I need a form on my WordPress website that users can input information into through dropdown fields.But i just dont want the information to go away after sending.I need them to still be able to come back at anytime and edit those information they inputted earlier and re-save.And meanwhile,i'll still be able have all the information of every user inputed at the wp backend .Which plugin or add-on can  I use.Kindly assist
Thanks

Comment: Bolaji - Welcome to WordPress Development. Questions where you are requesting plugin suggestions are considered "off-topic" (http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). What have you researched or attempted as a means of solving this?